# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid Validation with Dates

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a really simple IG on my page:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (id number, date_from date, date_to date)
```

IG is editable (selecting all 3 columns from my_table) and users are able to edit both date fields.
I'm trying to create a validation for the dates (function body returning error text):

```
begin

if TO_DATE(:date_from, 'MM/DD/YYYY') > TO_DATE(:date_to, 'MM/DD/YYYY') then return 
'To date must be prior From date';
else null;
end if;
 
end;
```

(all options on said validations haven't been modified)
Validation is not doing anything, not sure why.
Anybody can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Apex 23.1.1 on apex.oracle.com. I created sample table and interactive grid based on it.

- dates are in dd.mm.yyyy format
- validation is set to date **to** column, a function body that returns error text:

  ```
  return case when :date_from > :date_to then
                'To date must be prior From date'
         end;
  ```

This is how execution looks like:

[image]

Comment: Sorry to bother LittleFoot, I have another column (didn't include initially for simplicity) that user can also edit (status). Whenever status is clicked for edits, the 'date to' column gets a red aler (like in your picture) even if it is not touched. It's not allowing the user to save IG edits cause of this. Do you perhaps know why? (I have no other validations, nor dyn actions, etc)